# Create my own addresses, roads and ways on a custom world map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, openstreetmap, google-geocoding-api

I'm currently new using Google Maps API v3 Javascript, and I have some questions.

#### The project

It's for a specific RPG. This is a game with its own world map, its own cities, frontiers and roads. So a full map, which I can create easily any data to import in any database, xml, json, kml... ANYTHING ! :)
So I'd like to use any API to make a map for this game.

#### What I need

In fact, I'd like to create a whole new map, completely out of our world map.
So, I need to import datas about towns, cities, frontiers and roads.
Then, I need a system that can calculates the way between 2 cities by searching the available roads between the points.
I know it can be hard because it's almost making another full Google Map but for another "world", and I'd really like to make it.

#### My questions

Is it possible with Google Maps ? Or do I have to look for, like Openstreetmap or another ?
Do I have to develop a whole "Geocoder" server ? For sure it's gonna be less weight than Google, because this RPG's world is not bigger than France or England, and it's an RPG so there is not as much details as in our real world, but if it's really needed to make an API, let's do it then !
I put an example of the project on the web but I can't show it in public for security and copyright reasons, so I can send the link to some of you if you really need something more "concrete".

It would be such a real pleasure for you all to help me, or at least to guide me for all the "how-to's", cuz if this project comes to birth, it would be such an amazing unique work in any RPG game !

Comment: IGN made a custom map for GTA IV which as you might know has its own city called Liberty City. Check it out [here](http://grandtheftauto.ign.com/maps/1/Liberty-City-Map), it demonstrates some of the features you mention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might like to take a look at [Open Geofiction](https://wiki.opengeofiction.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), which uses OpenStreetMap technology to create an imaginary world. The fact that it's in standard OSM format allows you to use any OpenStreetMap-compatible route calculation system, and in fact any other software that handles the format.

You can sign up and build your own country, and the fact that your country is intended to be no larger than France means that there is plenty of room for your project. You can [request your own territory](https://wiki.opengeofiction.net/wiki/index.php/OGF:Frequently_asked_questions#How_do_I_request_a_territory.3F).

Comment: This is the best answer I could receive in years, thanks a lot for this link!
Even if I developed my own system with plain JSON & other stuff, this Geofiction project seems exactly like what I definitely need as a map data source!

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps will give you a "slippy map" framework, plus a lot of stuff specific to Earth: geocoding, places, routing over roads, etc.  The stuff specific to Earth is, well, specific to Earth, so not all that useful to you: I think all you could use Google Maps for is the slippy map framework, and given Google's licensing restrictions, you are probably better off using a different one, like Leaflet.

The Open Street Map project has two things: data about the Earth and tools for populating the data set.  While the data won't be interesting to you, the tools probably would be, and keeping the data on OSM format would allow you to use OSM routing and search tools.

For geocoding: it's your world, so you can determine what the street addresses look like, which might make it easier to geocode.  (One of the things that makes geocoding difficult on Earth is ambiguity: 234-3410 Mt. St. Michel Rd SE, Fooville, WA might be the same as 3410 SE Mount Saint Michel Road #234, Fooville, WA, 98279.)

Comment: Seems good to use personal data on OSM, but how do you do that ?
I'm trying to search on the web for tutorials, guides or API resources, but can't find anything. I think that my search engine has broken -_- (joke, of course)

Answer (score 2):

Using software from the OpenStreetMap ecosystem would work, but only if you are willing to invest considerable effort to set up all of the required software components, databases and so on.

To be clear, you wouldn't upload your personal data to the OpenStreetMap servers, but rather convert it to OpenStreetMap's data format. Depending on the size of the project, whether you want multiple users to be able to edit your database or are fine with a one-way export etc., you might either get away with just saving all data to a [.osm XML file](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/.osm), or you would have to set up your own instance of the ["Rails Port"](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/The_Rails_Port) (the OpenStreetMap database/API server). Either way, you can use editing tools such as [JOSM](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/) to view that data, which makes it much easier to e.g. debug your export code.

Once you have successfully exported your data to one of the OpenStreetMap data formats and have verified that it looks ok in an editor, you should be able to feed it to the existing tools for rendering, routing and geocoding that work on OpenStreetMap data. You'd have to plug several programs together, though, because there is no "one-stop-package" for all that functionality. Honestly, I'm not sure whether it's worth the effort, especially if you have no prior OpenStreetMap experience.

Comment: It's worth the effort, because once the projects will be online, it's gonna be some kind of a unique product for the entire community which is gonna use this app.
 
For now, I'm trying to learn how to use Leaflet, and trying to understand how all these systems work. It's really hard, I wish I had more time but anyway..
 
So, what you are advising to me is to set up the Rails Port, and convert some informations about my "new world" into OSM datas ? Then if I use OpenStreetMap for my app, will I be able to use only my database and not OSM's one ?

Comment: As I said, whether you need the Rails Port ... depends. It mostly helps with multi-user editing of the data and really large datasets. If you have an one-way automated export to .osm XML, you may not need it.

So if you are convinced you want to try this, I would start with the conversion. (And just for clarity: You will not be "using OpenStreetMap" for your app, you will use software that understands the OSM data format.)

Comment: Fine, I had some other advices about the apps used by OSM to render and manage all the maps. I think I'm gonna install Mapnik to render the maps, and ... And think again. I completely do not know how to use Mapnik to render maps from datas, furthermore I need to use my JPG file formatted in tilesets.
After that I need to make a tool for moving inside the map, zooming, and after that , use a travelling system.. I have time to do it, I'm just overwhelmed for now with all the possibilities and the fact that too few people know them to help me using it all ;)
Thanks a lot for your help ! :)

Comment: Hi Tordanik, I'm coming back for news after months of research and work ! Finally, I'm using Leaflet, I created my own map tiles generator, which only cuts and crops one really large image (this was what I need).
For the routes & markers, I add them in a MySQL database, with the power of Leaflet coordinates system, so I add routes and markers manually. This is good, because all coordinates are usable to create markers and polylines, but they're also understandable by any geocoding service.
 
For now, I only set up the database to have towns and routes to work with.

Comment: I'm currently looking for a good software which will make geocoding possible, but what I'm looking for is not really geocoding, it's more a "Routing" system.
For example, I have about 100 cities spread over the map of the game. I also created many routes, connected to each other either with a city or another route (meaning that any route has a "start" and "end" point, which is either a marker or another route start or end point).
 
What I need is to calculate the full route from the point A to B, especially the shortest route, or depending of some parameters (fixed in the db).
Any suggestion ?